# CSRF token missing or incorrect. with flask

Tags: python, flask, postman

[image]

I'm trying to post some data to a flask view function with postman. You can see the request in the screenshot. My function is:

```
@main.route('/renew')
def renew():
    R=Renew()
    R.setUp()
    R.test_renew()
    return 'renewed'
```

As you can see I'm getting:

```
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: Please post more information. Assuming `Renew()` is a `WT-Forms`-based form you need to provide a CSRF token in the POST body. To do so, open the page in Chrome, Ctrl+Shift+I & grab the hidden csrf token from the form to use when testing.